# Inserting data via macros (on top of other macros)

Tags: excel

I have a series of macros that will insert data pertaining to which button is selected.  The problem that I am having is that I have a series of 5 buttons each running a macro containing a different number of rows of data.  After the data is entered from the macro, I have the same 5 buttons for the user to select another group of data.  Since each macro is a different number of rows it keeps screwing up the formating (example: the 2nd set of macros is set to run in row 3, but when the first set is selected the data continues until row 5).  Any advise on how to fix this?

Here is my macro's code:

```
Sub Realestate() 

    Sheet14.Unprotect Password:="Loan101" 

    Range("AV1:CP20").Select 
    Selection.Copy 
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4 
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3 
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2 
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1 

    Range("A11:AU11").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("U13:AA13").Select 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Application!R[10]C[3]" 
    Range("I14:Q14").Select 

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Application!R[119]C[9]" 
    Range("K24:O24").Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Consumer Loan Request'!R[-4]C[-1]" 

    Range("P24").Select 
    Rows("20:20").RowHeight = 3 
    Rows("30:30").RowHeight = 3 

    Range("j12:w12").Select 

    Sheet14.Protect Password:="Loan101" 

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe seeing some code and some more details we might have some advice, yes.

Comment: Here's example of the code:

Comment: Sub Realestate()
'
' Realestate Macro
'

'
    Sheet14.Unprotect Password:="Loan101"
    Range("AV1:CP20").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A11:AU11").Select

Comment: Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("U13:AA13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Application!R[10]C[3]"
    Range("I14:Q14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Application!R[119]C[9]"
    Range("K24:O24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Consumer Loan Request'!R[-4]C[-1]"
    Range("P24").Select
    Rows("20:20").RowHeight = 3
    Rows("30:30").RowHeight = 3
    Range("j12:w12").Select
    Sheet14.Protect Password:="Loan101"
End Sub

Comment: I basically want the next macro to start wherever the first one ends and not on a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs several fixes to be optimized, but the way SO works is to answer one question each time so that future users will find it useful as well. I will hence, in this thread, limit to answer your question: "*How can I make a macro starting from the row where the previous one ended?*"

The trick is to store the value of the row in a global variable, i.e. a variable whose scope is not limited to the single macro but to the whole module. In order to reach this (please adapt this small example to your code, since nobody can see the project so this can only be a hint):

1) Declare the global variable on top of all macros:

```
Dim rowStart As Long
```

2) Write your macros:

```
Dim rowStart As Long
Sub Macro1()
    'code 
End Sub
Sub Macro2()
    'code
End Sub
```

So, here's the hint. Make your first macro perform some operations, for example putting 20 random numbers into the first 20 cells of the column "B":

```
Sub Macro1()
    For j = rowStart To rowStart + 20  'rowStart has not been modified yet, so it's equal to 0 by default
        Sheets("YourSheet").Range("B" & j+1).Value = Rnd() '"B" & j will be "B1" the first time, "B2" the second time etc.
    Next j
    rowStart = j 'here we store the value "20", i.e. the last value of j, into the global variable so that we can reuse it after
End Sub
```

Once this is done, let's say that your second macro will want to add other 10 random numbers to the existing list already created from the first macro. To do this:

```
Sub Macro2()
    For j = rowStart To rowStart + 10 'now rowStart = 20, so we will start from the last row where the previous macro ended! 
        Sheets("YourSheet").Range("B" & j+1).Value = Rnd()
    Next j
    rowStart = j 'now we store the value "30", so next time you want to know the last row used, you will know it
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, your code is very complicated to read and understand what it's doing (I imagine it's recorded since I still see the `ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn` command coming from you moving up and down your spreadsheet manually). 
So, my suggestion is to start from these two tips:

1. Global variables will help you to keep in memory the last rows touched from your macros;
2. String merging (`Range("B" & j)`) will help you to reference objects dinamically.

In general, use the Macro recorder to learn about the commands, but write your own code: it might take a bit longer in the beginning, but you will make sure that the code is flexible and able to adapt to any kind of similar problem. Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.org/) to get started with.